# Redirect to Cordova App

Tags: cordova, redirect, cordova-plugins, identity

I'm developing my first cordova app and want the users to be able to log in via my own identity server. Since the identity server is my own and I trust it, I'd like the app to navigate direct to my server's login page on start. This can be achieved by setting the windows's location to my local instance of my identity server, i.e.,

```
window.location.href = "https://10.0.2.2:5000"
```

Now, when the user has successfully completed login I'd like to be redirected back to may app. I provide the identity server with the redirect url `http://localshost` but when it attempts to redirect I get the following error

```
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED(http://localhost/#id_token=eyhjb.....
```

Is it possible to redirect back to a cordova app webview when I trust the site I've directed to? Or, should I always be trying to do this through the `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` or system browser even when I'm the owner of the identity server?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that works directly. But there is a smart workaround for your issue. Check the Cordova Plugin [Custom-URL-scheme](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme). You can specify an expression for a html link which automatically starts (restarts) the Cordova app. For example the link on the website after the successful login could be

```
<a href="mycoolapp://">Open my app</a>
```

or to overgive an information to your app that the login was successful

```
<a href="mycoolapp://?login=successful">Open my app</a>
```

Probably you can also call that link automatically per Javascript after the successful login of your user.

Best regards
Marc